# Magento $this->_redirect() does not work on an ajax response

Tags: development

I would like to know how to cut an ajax response specifically on the one page checkout saveBilling process (ajax) and redirect to the login page.

I am currently using this code

> $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');

but it only produces a ajax GET response.

```
public function checkGuestIfRegistered($email){

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id', 'email'))
                ->addFieldToFilter("email", array("eq" => $email));
    if($customer->count() >= 1){

        $result['error'] = $this->__('Please log in');
        $result['redirect'] = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

    }
}
```

saveBilling

```
public function saveBillingAction(){
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    //print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost('billing')['email']);
    $this->checkGuestIfRegistered($this->getRequest()->getPost('billing')['email']);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
        $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

        if (isset($data['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
        }
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

        if (!isset($result['error'])) {
            if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );
            } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'shipping-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
                );

                $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
            } else {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
            }
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your ajax response need to be process on the client side you can not use server side redirect.

Try

```
$result['error'] = -1;
$result['message'] = $this->__('Please log in');
$result['redirect'] = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

Update

```
public function checkGuestIfRegistered($email){

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id', 'email'))
                ->addFieldToFilter("email", array("eq" => $email));
    if($customer->count() >= 1){

        $result['error'] = -1;
        $result['message'] = $this->__('Please log in');
        $result['redirect'] = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then

```
if($this->checkGuestIfRegistered($this->getRequest()->getPost('billing')['email'])){
    return;
 }
```

*You may want to refactor the code and move the setBody out of checkGuestIfRegistered and return an empty array or $result*

Comment: this just pushes thru and processes additional ajax requests. it doesn't redirect me here is my complete code. I've already check it it passes the condition

Comment: Where is `checkGuestIfRegistered($email)` called from. Also can you check the response content of the ajax request

Comment: On the saveBilling action OnepageController

Comment: Can you add that function.. try adding `die()` and then check the response

Comment: I will add it above

Comment: it just keeps on pushing thru with other ajax processes

Comment: Take a look at my update, you may want to refactor the code and move the redirect and return an empty array or $result

Comment: Also did you test to see if add a `die` statement would work?

Comment: If you add a die() it should stop with either a blank result or the json object, but it will stop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27177/discussion-between-tom-cruz-and-r-s).

Comment: this is the response: {"error":"Please log in","redirect":"http:\/\/magento.localhost\/index.php\/customer\/account\/login
\/"}

Comment: no it doesn't redirect

Comment: Do you check your js error console?

Comment: yep no error... if I put a $result['message'] it works properly... the redirect can be seen as a ajax GET response on the console. but it just doesnt redirect.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Take a look at saveCheckoutMethod() in /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php